# Redirect to https and directory not working on Mobile LTE/3G connection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla site and sometimes the site will not load on mobile data. If I clear my browser and try to load the site on LTE it will not load, then I switch to 3g and it will load up. Then the same thing happens on 3G. I clear my browser and the site will not load, I switch to LTE and the site loads. I have no issues on home/office wifi.

The site and all of the plug-ins are up to date and then I have disabled any that are not being used.

I get "Safari can not open the page because it could not connect to the server."

if I try and go to sundenmanagement.com with out the https or home1 I get a "connection time out error"

I have the following code and please note I am no pro at this. I do have two htaccess files, one is in the htdocs and it is a copy of the one in the home1 folder.

I am trying to redirect all traffic to https and to the /home1/index.php then will need to figure out how to remove www. if it has been added.

index.php4 - is in the htdocs

`<?php header('Location: https://sundenmanagement.com/home1/');exit;?>`

htaccess  - it is the Joomla htaccess file and it is located where it says ## Begin - Custom redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sundenmanagement.com/home1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am not sure if this is to do with my cell provider or the redirects.
Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Redirect to `/home1/` or `/home1/index.php`? I assume you mean the former?

Comment: @Jason If you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post your Joomla questions there.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will now as I am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> "could not connect to the server" / "connection time out error"

These are network / DNS errors, which don't have anything to do with your server-side code/redirects since the request is not even reaching your server.

Having said that, 301 redirects are cached by the client and your redirects are certainly wrong if you are trying to redirect all requests to HTTPS + `/home1/`...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sundenmanagement.com/home1/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

The first rule redirects from www to non-www, but redirects to HTTP, even if the initial request was HTTPS. So this will result in multiple redirects. And when used in the `/home1/.htaccess` file this actually removes the `/home1/` subdirectory from the URL!

The second and third rules perform the same check - is the request HTTP? So the third rule is never processed and when used in the root directory, the request is never forced to `/home1/`.

If you are not concerned about having a "generic" solution (you've mixed generic/specific rules above) then in the root `/.htaccess` you simply need to force `/home1/` in a single directive, you don't need any other directives here since everything else would seem to be handled by the `/home1/.htaccess` file. For example:

```
# /.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect everything to the "/home1/" subdirectory (HTTPS + non-www)
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/home1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want a "generic" redirect, without explicitly including the domain name, then you could change the above rule to the following, however, this does assume you don't have any other subdomains (except for www):

```
# Redirect everything to the "/home1/" subdirectory (HTTPS + non-www)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/home1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then in the `/home1/.htaccess` file you would have the following canonical redirects together with your other Joomla directives. For example:

```
# /home1/.htaccess

# www to non-www (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks you for the info! I have changed out the code and get a too many redirects error now. Any joomla pros know if I should have the joomla htaccess file in the home1 directory or the htdocs. I have two of the same htaccesss files as I copied the joomla one to the htdocs from the home1 directroy so i think it is running all the joomla rewrites twice.

Comment: "if I should have the joomla htaccess file in the home1 directory or the htdocs" - it depends how Joomla is configured. But if you are redirecting everything to the `/home1/ subdirectory then it makes sense that the Joomla directives should only be the `/home1/.htaccess` file, as mentioned above. Presumably `/home1/` is included in the URL-path of your Joomla URLs? Edit your question to include the current state of your `.htaccess` files.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try as I have broke the site now. lol on a desktop pc it adds a bunch of numbers and the htdocs to the url between the domain name and home1 folder.